# Angle within a rectangular-based prism

Tags: linear-algebra, triangles, plane-geometry

I've tried to find solutions to similar problems to see how this question should be solved but I didn't have much luck.

A rectangular-based prism is shown below. I need to determine the size of angle ABC using the vector dot product.

I know how to do the vector dot product for easier problems but this one has me a bit stuck.

[Prism](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjwGP.png)

I created a right triangle and worked out that 4^2 + 1^2 = 17^2 so AC (hypotenuse) = √17
and the angle would be arctan(1/4) which is approx. 14 degrees.

I'm just not sure where to take it from here and how to actually get angle ABC. I just need to know the steps required to get me there.

How would you do it?

Comment: What is the vector from B to A  in your coordinate system?  How about B to C?  What are the magnitudes of each and what is the dot product?